# How to direct explorer.exe from VB?

Tags: vb.net, windows

I can replace explorer.exe as the program to be executed after booting by replacing it in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon. But how can I embed it in a software as a program so that it is done automatically when my software is installed? And what software can I use for this? Also my main programs are in VB, so how can I redirect to explorer.exe after the work in VB is done??

Answer (score 0):

To answer the VB part of your question, you can call Process.Start() to invoke IE.

Sources :

(1) http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-vbnet

(2) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/08b57b26-72c3-4896-bdb8-b8d52558d0f1/vb-express-code-to-run-external-application